# Is OpenCL a shared, distributed or hybrid memory system

Tags: memory, opencl, cpu-architecture

I'm having a hard time understanding if OpenCL and in particular OpenCL 2.0+ is a shared, distributed or a distributed shared memory architecture, in particular with a computer that has many OpenCL devices in the same PC.

In particular, I can see that It's a shared memory system in the fact that they can all access global memory but theirs a network-like aspect with the compute units that makes me question if it could classicly be classed as a distributed-shared memory architecture

Comment: grain of salt: OpenCL 2.0 SVM: virtual address sharing: `DSM`. Relaxed memory hieararchy with software-side synch: `distributed`. Compute units in GPU: `shared` because they see same memory with a proper way of access. So I think all of them is combined.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it from a generic OpenCL coding perspective, your answer is "yes, maybe, unless it's not."

If you are talking about some specific hardware, there are (somewhere) clear and concise answers of how things work on the chip(s) and how OpenCL uses them.

By examining the OpenCL capacities and capabilities at runtime, you could modify some parameters of your OpenCL program or choose one of various kernels that is the best fit.